# Parent Child Relationships PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a table like this:

```
**id     name     parent_id**
1       X         2 
2       Y         2
3       Z         1
4       A         5
5       B         6
6       C         1


I want output look like this: 
**name       *parent name***
X           Y
Y           Y
Z           X
A           B
B           C
C           X
```

Is it possible to do it with one query by using JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select son.name as name, father.name as parent_name from table_name as son left join table_name as father ON son.parent_id = father.id`

Answer (score 4):

You need to perform a self-join:

```sql
SELECT child.name AS `name`, parent.name AS `parent name`
FROM   my_table AS child JOIN my_table AS parent ON parent.id = child.parent_id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aa60/1/0).

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you. Though the default for JOIN is INNER JOIN - I was missing the top level parent. So I changed this to LEFT JOIN and was able to get my "Default" top level parent that had no parents above it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to do this

Example:

```
SELECT
    table.name
    , parent.name as parent_name
FROM
    table
LEFT JOIN
    parent ON parent.parent_id = table.parent_id
WHERE
    table.visible = 1
```

After that you will handle the response from your query in php cycle through returned array of items(array's or object's - depends on what MySQL abstraction you use), save the needed in your own array, or just encoding this array to JSON.

Note: I don't know for what you need this, but it's good idea to include `table.id` in the result, if you want latter to be able to identify one record.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 2 tables:

1. `product`
2. `product_parent`

Then, you run a query like this:

```
SELECT product.name, product_parent.name
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_parent
ON product.product_parent_id=product_parent.id
```